# Salesforce multiselect picklist value as Journey builder entry event is not working as expected

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I have a journey builder event which fires when there is a update in the lead object. The entry criteria is based on the values of multiselect picklist. The multiselect picklist values are A, B and C. Based on the value changes a new email must be triggered for each value. For example if some one adds A as new value then email related to A should be fired.

I have used the entry condition like field contains A or contains B or Contains C.

However the rule fires only when i completely remove the values from the field and add them again. Updating along with existing values not triggering email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These triggers are only invoked if changed from a non-matching value to a matching value. So if your field has the possible values A, B, C and D and your entry criteria is `field = A OR field = B OR field = C` the journey is only triggered if the original value is D and is changed to either A, B or C. If you change from A to B for example, your journey won't be triggered.

> When a record is updated, the rule runs only if the record meets rule criteria after the update. The rule does not run when a record that previously met rule criteria is updated.
> (Source: [Journey Builder Documentation: Salesforce Data Event](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/using_the_salesforce_sales_and_service_cloud_event/))

Comment: My understanding was if we use OR condition its enough to satisfy any one of the condition.

Comment: I need to trigger emails based on the value changes and in this case the only option is to create multiple journeys?

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand the documentation creating multiple journeys is necessary in that case.